# If $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ et $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|b_n|$ converge, so $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nb_n$ as well.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, examples-counterexamples

Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|b_n|$ converging series. Proof that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nb_n$ converges as well. What happens if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n$ doesn't converge absolutely?

I would like to know if my proof for the statement holds and if my counter-example for second part works as well. Thank you in advance!

*Proof.* (First part)

First of all, as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, we deduce that $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$. Therefore, $\exists N \ \forall n\ge N$: $0<|a_n|<1$

Then, by the analogous reasoning we obtain that: $\exists N' \ \forall n\ge N': 0<|b_n|<1$

Let $n_0= \max\{N,N'\}$. Thus, $\forall n\ge n_0$ we have that:

$0<|a_n||b_n|=|a_nb_n|<|b_n|$. So, by comparaison, as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|b_n|$ exists, we conclude that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nb_n$ converges absolutely.

*Counter-example* (If $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n$ converges, but not absolutely)

Let $(a_n)=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2}}$ and $(b_n)=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt[3]{n+1}}$. By alternating series criterion the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n$ converge ($\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n$ doesn't converge absolutely). But,

$a_nb_n=\frac{1}{n+1}$ and so $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nb_n$ doesn't converge.

Comment: Your proof is fine. Your counter-example works

Comment: @Fred Thank you very much for your feedback. But was it really necessary to define $n_0$ in my proof? As i worked (and i had to) with $N$ and $N'$ which are certainly not equal

Comment: Why did you define $N'$? $|a_n b_n|< |b_n|$ holds for $n \geq N$ anyway.

Comment: @Gary I see your point. But, if we had to work with $b_n$ and not $|b_n|$, would it make sens to define $N'$? In this statement's case i see why it is useless,thank you